# iFrame's https content blocking Jquery code on page to run in IE8. Do you any have ideas?

Tags: jquery, http, iframe, https

I asked question about my code not working with iframe yesterday.

I found out, that the problem wasn't actually with the frame, it was with loaded content - adding https src="" caused jquery to stop running

After searching for some time, it became clear that I should not mix simple http page with https content.

Do you now how to solve this problem. I don't have server. it is just local page accessing another local page (which is actully server https login page and I have local access to it). So I don't know how to add SSL sertificate or to make my page https.

If someone have any ideas please help...

Comment: Are you getting a notice in the browser for this. I think if firefox a notice appear, and ask for the permission. And once you allow that it acts normally. And normally the notice appear beside the address bar

Comment: I added my browser type - IE8